# An adjective for something that will happen next month

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

English is a so cool that I believe even an adjective which means "happening next month" exists.

> Tom is a rather strange man. He always has the urge to attend a ***_*__*_*___** event but he always changes his mind after fortnight. Nobody can really account for why he loses interest just about one week before the event, not even himself.

If such an adjective does not exist, how about an adjective that means "happening in one (or two) months' time"? Does the database of English words have space for such a word?

Please do not suggest words like "future", "coming", "forthcoming", "prospective", "upcoming", "impending" because they are certainly not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Looks like you should have specified that 'next' is also not an answer you are looking for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a word for this — *proximo*, meaning "in or of the next (coming) month". It is a loan word from Latin (*proximo mense* — "in the next month", as opposed to *ultimo mense* — "in the last (preceding) month".

E.g. (from freedictionary), "on the 10th [*proximo*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proximo)" (10th of coming month).

Since you want a term that does not specifically refer to the *coming next month* but to *any next month*, you can also use the term *proximate* (month) in the sense of coming immediately next.

Comment: So in the OP's example, how would this be used?

Comment: I think this is incorrect. My understanding is that in Spanish, [próximo](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-spanish/next-month) can be used in a general sense to mean "sometime next month". But English, the (now obsolete) Latin *proximo* and *ultimo* were only normally used in commercial correspondence (invariably abbreviated as *prox/ult*), and even then only in respect of *specific* calendar dates (such as *Further to our letter of 10th ult...*).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 'proximate' in that scenario?

Comment: I double dare you to actually say or write "he always has the urge to attend a proximo event", just so you realize that it makes you sound like — well, you will realize what it makes you sound like.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "the next month's event".

Comment: Or in fact, "the next-month event", if you absolutely insist on it being a single word, which of course is a pointless requirement to begin with.